# Responsive html layout crashing

Tags: html, css, layout

I need to make responsive layout, but my menu crashing like in the picture. I need to make menu in the right position, so in my css I added right:0px. How I should make menu with right position and working responsive.

This is how it looks with right position.
[image]
[image]

But when I delete right:0px; everything is working, BUT I need right position.
Example without right position
[image]
[image]

```
 <div class="row" id="menu_section">
  <div style=" margin-top:20px" class="four columns">
    <img class="img" src="images/logo.png">
  </div>
  <div class="eight columns">

    <div id="menuSection">
      <div class="menu top">
        <div class="item">Registrati</div>
        <div class="item">Accedi</div>
        <div class="item"><img src="images/shoppingCart.png"></div>
     </div>

      <div class="menu bottom">
        <div class="item"><b>C</b>osa fare</div>
        <div class="item"><b>O</b>rdina ora</div>
        <div class="item"><b>A</b>ziende</div>
        <div class="item"><b>F</b>ilosofia</div>
        <div class="item"><b>C</b>ontatti</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
#menuSection{
  right: 0px;
  bottom:0px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

#menu_section{
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.menu.top{
margin-left:auto;
text-align: right;
padding-bottom:20px;
}

.menu.bottom{
margin-top:auto;
text-align: right;
}

.img{
max-width:100%; 
position: relative; 
bottom: 0; 
display:table;     
display:block;
margin:auto;"
}
```

Comment: can you show css or link?

Comment: share your CSS file also

Comment: add float: right to your menu class in the css.

Comment: @Kami if I add float:right; ,  when my menu is not in right the position, it be a little centeder.

Comment: i wouldn't go with absolute positioning for a responsive header. stick to static and play with mediaqueries. or post more code (or jsfiddle) for additional help